# how to instantiate a singleton class in Startup.cs and then use in net core?

Tags: c#, .net-core, singleton

I am creating an object from an object created in my appsetting.json, I add it through singleton but then I don't know how to access those values.

My class:

```
public class UserConfiguration
{
    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string SecretKey{ get; set; }
}
```

In my startup.cs

```
 var userCfg = Configuration.GetSection("UserConfig").Get<UserConfiguration>(); //.> success i've values
 services.AddSingleton(userCfg);

 services.AddControllers();
```

and i want use this class and I call this class from my controller api.

```
public class UserService : BaseService
{
    public UserService(IConfiguration config): base(configuration)
    {

    }

    public string GetData()
    {
        var userConfg = new UserConfiguration();
        var key = user.SecretKey;  //--> null but a instance is empty

        return "ok"
    }
}
```

but I don't know how to rescue the values ​​of the singleton that I loaded in the Startup.cs

Comment: I think you need to do something like this: https://medium.com/shemseddine-on-code/net-core-configuration-settings-binding-c7df1b56877

Comment: Thanks!! this article work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're registering UserConfiguration as Singleton with DI container, you can inject this object UserService constructor:

```cs
public class UserService : BaseService
{
    private UserConfiguration _userConfiguration;
    public UserService(IConfiguration config, UserConfiguration userConfiguration): base(configuration)
    {
        _userConfiguration = userConfiguration; //Injected in constructor by DI container
    }

    public string GetData()
    {
        var key = _userConfiguration .SecretKey;

        return "ok"
    }
}
```

However recommended approach to pass application configuration information to services is by using the [Options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

```cs
services.Configure<UserConfiguration>(Configuration.GetSection("UserConfig"));

services.AddControllers();
```

Add then access the configuration option:

```cs
public class UserService : BaseService
{
    private UserConfiguration _userConfiguration;
    public UserService(IConfiguration config, IOptions<UserConfiguration> userConfiguration): base(configuration)
    {
        _userConfiguration = userConfiguration.Value; //Injected in constructor by DI container
    }

    public string GetData()
    {
        var key = _userConfiguration .SecretKey;

        return "ok"
    }
}
```